# Java 8 syntax confusing to understand

Tags: java, java-8

Someone replied to a question with an answer I'm having trouble understanding.

the first answer I understand is:

```
Double[][] inverse = new Double[temp.length][temp[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < temp[0].length; j++)
        inverse[i][j] = temp[i][j];
    }
}
```

but this answer which requires Java 8 has me confused:

```
Double[][] inverse = Arrays.stream(temp)
    .map(d -> Arrays.stream(d).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new))
    .toArray(Double[][]::new);
```

Does Arrays.stream(temp) return each row of temp?

then the next line does the map take each element in the row convert it to an object and place it in a 1d array>

and then the next line takes the 1darray and places it a 2darray?

Comment: What does the Javadoc of `Arrays#stream(T[])` say?

Comment: here's what it says, stream(T[] array)
Returns a sequential Stream with the specified array as its source. not very helpful

Comment: Ok, next step. What is a `Stream`? _A sequence of elements [...]_. Ok, the array's variables are its elements. The elements can sometimes be arrays themselves, as is the case here ("2D" array). So the elements of the `Stream` are the array variables. So it streams those arrays, converts them to `Double` arrays by boxing each `double` element, then collects those `Double[]` into a `Double[][]`. If that's what you meant by your explanation, you are correct.

Comment: Don’t say 2-d array, this is not Fortran. It’s an array of arrays. Which works since each entry in the stream gets mapped to an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This all process take a `double[][]` and returns a boxed copy, a `Double[][]`**

---

> Does Arrays.stream(temp) return each row of temp ?

[***`Arrays.stream(T[])`***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) return a sequence of the elements contained in the given array. `temp` is an array of `double[]` so the stream will be of `double[]` (so yes "rows" if you see it as a 2D array), in the next operation`d` will be  `double[]`

---

> Then the next line does the map take each element in the row convert it to an object and place it in a 1d array?

[***`Arrays.stream(double[])`***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-double:A-) returns a `Stream` of `double` values, the ones of the `double[] d` (local variable). These variables are `boxed` to `Double` and put together to make a `Double[]`

---

> Then the next line takes the 1darray and places it a 2darray?

Then all these `Double[]` are put together to build a `Double[][]`